# Latex Not Recognizing png R graph

Tags: graphics, external-files, png

Please help!

I made a Latex (using texworks) and it will not recognize my png file. I have the file in the same directory as the .tex and, when I scroll over the command in tex works, the image appears. I used R to compile the graph. Below are my packages:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,draft]{article}

%\setlength{\columnsep}{.1in}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color} %added
\usepackage{longtable} %added
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{amsopn}
\usepackage{amsxtra}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{harvard}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\renewcommand\harvardurl[1]{\textbf{URL:} \url{#1}}
\geometry{letterpaper} 
\geometry{margin=1in} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{-5pt}
\lhead{}\chead{}\rhead{\phantom{X} \thepage}
```

All I am getting is this image below in my document,
[image]

Please, any help would be appreciated. I'm on a strict deadline!

Best,

-Chuck

Comment: `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,draft]{article}` is the issue: with the `draft` option, `graphics` doesn't include images. Either remove it here or use `\usepackage[final]{graphics}`. (There is be a dupe for this, hence not answering but commenting.)

Comment: Many blessings Joseph Wright! You answered my question to the tee, I removed the draft option. Thank you so much!